# App won't uninstall from Smartwatch 2

Tags: sony-smartwatch

I've deployed an Android app that interfaces with the Sony Smartwatch 2, and generally, it's working well. However, I have a user reporting that when he uninstalls the app from his phone, the watch component is not uninstalled.

I understand that the un/installation of the two should be linked, and in my testing (and for most of my users), that works fine. What might this user try to force the app to uninstall from the watch?

Comment: Have they tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: What's the name of the app? I can have a look on the issue and provide you with some feedback.

Comment: The app is Wearable Widgets, package name com.wearablewidgets. I haven't heard anything back from the user (this is a remote support situation) so for all I know the problem may have fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

The user could be right. I've observed the issue only once for ca. twenty (20) installing/uninstalling rounds. However I did not found the way to reproduce it and I can't state what circumstances can cause such behaviour.

Did you've got information from the user on what phone, Android release, Smart Connect or SmartWatch 2 software version this issue occurred?

The only thing he can do to remove Wearable Widgets instance from SmartWatch is to reset the watch (Settings -> Reset SmartWatch).